# RPM Build, how to get the path where the RPM package been "rpm -ivh" at shell script running by '%post' macro

Tags: shell, redhat, rpm

**I'm a newbie in rpm build. and i did my best i can to describe the little complicated question with my amature english...**

i have a script(.sh) with some code,what the script do is to setup the code,and it need some user input.

sadly i found out scripts running by rpm can not get user input.

> and i know that's not right usage. i'm not trying to get user input
> anymore.

> my question is:

**i'm now trying to get those input with a config file along with the rpm package,but i don't know how to get the rpm package path at the SPEC file macros or the script file running by SPEC file macros.**

Comment: i tried `pwd` in `%post` and the script file in `%post`, they all get just `'/'`,i need to get where the rpm package placed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpm` packages are not supposed to "adapt" themselves to user input. I would recommend you to make sure the installation of the package is always the same. Once the package is installed, you can tell users how to configure the program.

Take `git` for example: it provides `/etc/gitconfig` which contains the default packaged configuration. Users can then make their changes to the configuration and save those in `~/.gitconfig`. Thus the user configuration is separated from the packaged configuration, so you can keep updating `git` without losing your configuration.

Comment: thanks,I'm sure that’s the regular usage. however at my circumstance,without automaticly run the setup script, what the rpm package actually do would be only unpack the files, and i'm been instructed to make a rpm package to do the setup.

Comment: in that case I would package the setup script and the setup configuration script such that it can run in the `%post` step

Comment: It is NOT possible. Chris is right. IIRC rpm even close STDIN of scriptlets. You can write something on output. But you cannot take user input. Full stop. The best practice is to provide Ansible rule to configure the application.